# Where are the Jetty Log File with Solr

Tags: solr, jetty

I've downloaded Solr with Jetty as it is recommended on the Solr Tutorial. But, I don't succeed to find the log file associated with Jetty.

Could someone please help me to find it ?

Thanks

Corentin

Comment: Have you checked the log folder?

Comment: If you talk about "example/logs" directory, it's empty. I found some informations on this page : [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LoggingInDefaultJettySetup)
I'm trying to configure these logs following this page but I'm not really sure that it's made for what I'm looking for. I want to see if Jetty isn't a bottleneck when I index documents with solr. Can I see in the Jetty logs if Jetty can absorbe all the Http requests that I send to it with Solr ?